# How to make a Cross XHR request with XHR header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I don't want to know how to make cross XHR request, i want to know how to make cross xhr request with XHR header (X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest ) <-- I want this header to get sent with request to server, when i try with traditional way of http.setRequestHeader("","")
where var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

it doesn't work. Wondering, what is the way to do that?

p.s: ALL request will be POST based

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional headers triggers a [preflight OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) request which must get a response with suitable CORS headers before the browser will make the POST request.

You need to configure the server to respond to the OPTIONS request and say that the non-standard header is allowed.